# Send change blob url to an image that the axios can handle it

Tags: reactjs, image, axios

I have a problem. I have a file upload created in React. Unfortunately I get only the blob url back, for example `blob = "blob:http://localhost:3000/image"`. But it didn't work. In Postman I can create directly something for files. How can I create my blob to a right img, that the backend can handle it? The backend takes a Buffer. I got with my code `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.` How can I create the blob url to an Buffer array so the backend can handle it?

What I try:

Unfortunately with an error

```
// This is my URL
blob = "blob:http://localhost:3000/image"

const blobToBase64 = blob => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
  });
};


var base64; 
blobToBase64(blob).then(res => {
  // do what you wanna do
  console.log(res); // res is base64 now
  base64 = res;
});

data = base64;

axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/upload/", {
        data: data,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log("WORKS IMAGE")
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Postman query

```
    var axios = require('axios');
    var FormData = require('form-data');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', fs.createReadStream('/C:/Kazim/test.png'));
    
    var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'localhost:4000/upload/',
      headers: { },
      data : data
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

My buffer should look like this

```
{
  image: {
    name: 'test.png',
    data: <Buffer 89 124e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 58 00 00 0d 58 48 44 52 00 00 07 ce 00 00 08 ce 08 02 11 00 11 e3 a9 f1 77 12 00 00 01 73 52 58 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 
more bytes>,
    size: 21220,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    md5: '2f54581b868376d15d5fcaf63d',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use base64? Why you cannot use FormData API?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. No, I don't have to use it. I was just trying. However, the `Base64` didn't work and I saw that in Postman an` array buffer` is sent. The `FormData API` sounds promising. Do you know how I can convert a `blob URL` into an `array buffer`, or how I can make the backend receive it?

Comment: You can set a blob as value in FormData, and then send it. In this is a native way for sending files to back end